# Where can I get stats on mouse clicks?

Tags: data-request

I'm interested in finding out whether people tend to click the mouse faster when it's cold or hot, if the time of day affects the speed of mouse clicks, and lots of other information like that.

Does anyone know where I can get this kind of information?